# How to dispatch store actions in namespaced modules ( NuxtJS)?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

I have made lots of research and since keywords are always similar I cannot find a correct way of usage store modules in nuxtjs. I will shorten the codes to make it readable. In my nuxtjs application, I  am trying to reach my `vuex` modules in my home.page but instead I get

```
pages/index.vue

TypeError
Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch('articles/fetchIndexArticles')
        .then(() => this.$store.dispatch('videolessons/fetchIndexVideolessons'))
        .then(() => {
```

While creating `modules` first in the `store` folder i have created an `index.js` file:

```js
import Vuex from "vuex";
import articles from "./modules/articles";
// ...
import videolessons from "./modules/videolessons";

const debug = process.env_NODE_ENV !== 'production';

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    articles,
    books,
    members,
    pages,
    status,
    user,
    videolessons,
  },
  strict: debug,
  plugins: [],
})
```

and basically my modules are similar to my `articles` module:

```js
const getDefaultState = () => {
  return {
    indexArticles: [],
  }
}
const state = getDefaultState()
const getters = {
  indexArticles (state) {
    return state.indexArticles
  },
}
const mutations = {
  fetchStart (state) {
    state.loading = true
  },
  fetchEnd (state) {
    state.loading = false
  },
  setIndexArticles (state, pArticles) {
    state.indexArticles = pArticles
    state.errors = {}
  },
  setError (state, errors) {
    state.errors = errors
  },
  resetState (state) {
    Object.assign(state, getDefaultState())
  }
}
const actions = {
  // ...
  async fetchIndexArticles ({ commit }) {
    try {
      const response = await articlesService.fetchIndexArticles()
      commit('fetchStart')
      commit('setIndexArticles', response.data)
      commit('fetchEnd')
      return response
    } catch (error) {
      commit('setError', error)
      this._vm.$q.loading.hide()
    }
  },
...
}
export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations
}
```

and in my `index` page:

```html
<script>
import store from '../store/'
export default {
  computed: {
    indexarticles() {
        return this.$store.getters['articles/indexArticles'];
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch('articles/fetchIndexArticles')
        .then(() => this.$store.dispatch('videolessons/fetchIndexVideolessons'))
         ...
        .then(() => {
            this.isLoading = false;
    });
  }
};
</script>
<template>...</template>
```

can you help to correct my `store` modules?

Thanks

ps:

```
videolessons.js

const getDefaultState = () => {
  return {
    indexvideolessons: [],
  }
}
const state = getDefaultState()
const getters = {
  indexVideolessons (state) {
    return state.indexvideolessons
  },
}
const mutations = {
  setIndexVideolessons (state, pVideolessons) {
    state.indexvideolessons = pVideolessons
    state.errors = {}
  },
}
const actions = {

  async fetchIndexVideolessons ({ commit, dispatch }) {
    try {
      const response = await videolessonsService.fetchIndexVideolessons()
      commit('setIndexVideolessons', response.data)
      return response
    } catch (error) {
      commit('setError', error)
    }
  },
}
export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations
}
```

Comment: I don't know Nuxt very well but I don't think you should be making UI changes in your actions. What even is `this._vm.$q.loading`?

Comment: @Phil, that is code from quasar, sorry I have forgotten to delete that part, I am modifying from quasar to nuxtjs, because quasar caused me many problems while using nuxt, I have removed that part and edited my question.

Comment: `.then(this.$store.dispatch('videolessons/fetchIndexVideolessons'))` looks wrong. Normally it would be something like `.then(() => this.$store.dispatch('videolessons/fetchIndexVideolessons'))`

Comment: I have modified like that but still the error same, I am adding videolessons module.

Comment: The error message and code in your question still looks the same

Comment: @Phil after your edit, I have removed then block and it worked but when I put back, it does not work, I think best option is to use computed properties, my logic is wrong in the first place am I right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225649/discussion-between-ytsejam-and-phil).

Comment: I think you're creating your store incorrectly for Nuxt. See the examples here ~ https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/store. I don't think you're meant to manually create the new `Vuex.Store()`

Comment: @Phil, I realised that, it was about database server was down and empty, I have restarted and filled now it works,  I need to edit safe fallbacks for all steps. shall I edit my question or make an explanation for this situation?